# Why Input box going out of the div box after giving padding to it with 100% width

Tags: html, css, forms

I'm trying to create a form input with 100% of same width of the container but everything is working fine until I provide padding to input boxes and when I'm using padding for the `<input type="text"> <input type="password">` these two boxes go out of the div but for `<input type="button">` it works fine can anyone tell me what is the issue and how to fix it..

```css
 body{
        background-color: #eee;
        font-family: Arial;
      }
      .login {
          width: 400px;
          background-color: white;
          margin: 0 auto;
          margin-top: 40px;
          text-align: center;
          padding: 5px 15px 30px 15px;
          box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px RGBA(0, 0, 0, 0.39);
      }
      input {
          width: 100%;
          padding: 10px 13px;
          margin-bottom: 10px;
      }
```

```html
    <div class="login">
      <h2>Log In</h2>
      <form>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Email">
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password">
        <input type="button" value="Log In">
      </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Best to do if you want a 100% width, is set the padding in % and deduct that amount from your 100%. That way it will always be a total of 100% :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is how box model works. When you add 100% width it is applied to content. And an extra padding breaking the alignment. But you can change the box model to count the width from border.

Add [Box Sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) to input fields

```
input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: @NehaManchal Glad to help :)